# Prevent Doxygen from including unwanted comments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, doxygen

Given the following comment:

```
/// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// @class  Foo
/// @brief  Description of Foo.
/// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Doxygen outputs:

```
Describes a screen region in pixels, relative to some other region. ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

How can I prevent it from including the forward slashes?

EDIT: I need the /// followed by a space because it's the only way I know of to allow Visual Studio to highlight one type of comment (in this case documentation) in a different color to other comments (code comments, in my current project). This precludes me from simply removing the space on the first and last line of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the doxygen manual: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html

If you remove the spaces between the first /// and the trailing slashes, it should work as you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I'm stuck with the space - it's the only way I can get Visual Studio to highlight documentation comments in a different color to code comments. Can you think of another workaround? I'll peruse the manual in the meantime.

Comment: To clarify, my comment must start with three slashes followed by a space - I don't care what comes after the space.

Comment: Can you try removing all the trailing slashes? It looks like rule 3 is preventing you from having a space *and* all the slashes.

Comment: That works - although it now leaves my comment block less visible. It's an acceptable, if not ideal, solution.

Comment: I don't see a way around it given your requirement and the doxygen spec. If you wanted them to be visible you could surround it with lines of regular comments but that seems like overkill. Have you tried looking at your visual studio settings to change it to something more compatible with doxygen?

Comment: Yes, I even posted a question on stack overflow about that - the only way (that I'm aware of) to have different comment colors is with /// as one color, and all other comments as another. I tend to agree with your assesment - I believe that inserting a blank line in between the comments with trailing slashes, and the actual documentation comments would work - but that means wasting two extra lines per comment block.